# How to play radio on background IOS7

Tags: ios, uiwebview, stream

In my application i want to play a radio so i have used the `UIWebView` to play it now the problem is when come back its not playing in background please tell is that passable to play the radio in background using `UIWebView`.

My Play code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
     NSString *stream =@"http://centova.oxines.com/tunein/jesusredeems.pls";
     NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:stream];
     NSURLRequest *urlrequest =[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webview loadRequest:urlrequest];

}
```

How to achieve this one?

Comment: You will need play the stream yourself and not use `UIWebView`, use something like [AudioStreamer](https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer)

Comment: @rckoenes please tell is that possiable to bring the radio into notification center

Comment: No, you can not add stuff (widgets) to the notification center. You are however able to let you app be controlled by the iPod controls and it will therefore also work on the iPod controls in the control center and headsets. Have a look at [`MPNowPlayingInfoCenter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPNowPlayingInfoCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)